# Hibernate - Dynamic Instantiation usando factory

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, factory

Sei que utilizando o Dynamic Instantiation do hibernate posso instanciar um objeto de acordo com um construtor.

O Problema:
Preciso otimizar o máximo o sistema, e com isso acabado criando 5+ construtores em uma mesma classe.

Quero saber se é possível utilizar o padrão Factory junto com o Dynamic Instantiation.

HQL Atual `select new br.com.domain.dto.SolicitacaoDTO(s.id, s.beneficiario.nome, s.dataRegistro, s.statusSolicitacao) from Solicitacao s`

Se pudesse utilizar o padrão Factory

```
select new br.com.factory.dto.SolicitacaoDTO.consulta(s.id, s.beneficiario.nome, s.dataRegistro, s.statusSolicitacao) from Solicitacao s
```

Caso tenha alguma sugestão de como resolver este problema de outra forma, estou de portas abertas para sugestões ou correções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu consegui entender bem o que você precisa, posso dizer que pela documentação do Hibernate ele não ofere a opção de chamar um recurso de consulta ao instanciar o objeto através do Dynamic Instantiation.

Ele possibilita recurso para uso em um construtor:

```
Example 11.27. Dynamic instantiation example - constructor(Doc do Hibernate)
select new Family( mother, mate, offspr )
   from DomesticCat as mother
   join mother.mate as mate
   left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

Para uso através de lista:

```
Example 11.28. Dynamic instantiation example - list (Doc do Hibernate)
select new list(mother, offspr, mate.name)
  from DomesticCat as mother
  inner join mother.mate as mate
  left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
```

Ou através de mapas:

```
Example 11.29. Dynamic instantiation example - map (Doc do Hibernate)
select new map( mother as mother, offspr as offspr, mate as mate )
   from DomesticCat as mother
   inner join mother.mate as mate
   left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
select new map( max(c.bodyWeight) as max, min(c.bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n )from Cat c
```

Talvez a otimização que deseja fique em conseguir carregar as informações que precisa para um desses formatos.

Comment: Dessa forma que você postou que eu estou fazendo hoje. Porém da maneira que eu quero(delegar para uma factory ou builder) fazer não é possível.